# What is the point of declaring the constructor explicit in an empty struct?

Tags: c++

I was browsing a GCC header file recently and found this:
`struct defer_lock_t { explicit defer_lock_t() = default; };`

Why is the constructor declared explicit versus just being an empty `struct defer_lock_t {}`?

My understanding is that this type is used with a `constexpr` for constructor overloading.  I'm a bit fuzzy about the `explicit` keyword but I think I somewhat understand its function.

Comment: For a default constructor, or a constructor taking two or more arguments, it's not really needed. The `explicit` keyword is most useful to prohibit implicit conversions using "conversion constructors" (constructors taking a single argument).

Comment: As for the specific structure, it's take out of context and it's hard to say anything specific. You might need to look deeper into how the structure is used to learn why the constructor is made explicit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The point is that `defer_lock_t` construction is never implicit. While if the constructor was not declared as explicit it would participate in implicit construction.

Consider this example:

```
struct explicit_t { explicit explicit_t() = default; };
struct implicit_t { implicit_t() = default; };

void foo(explicit_t){}
void bar(implicit_t){}

int main() {
    //foo({});         // implicit - error
    foo(explicit_t{}); // explicit - ok
    bar({});           // implicit - ok
    bar(implicit_t{}); // explicit - ok
}
```

This can be desirable when `explicit_t` has important semantics that are needed to read and understand the code. Calling `foo({})` might be dangerous, because the reader is not aware of what is actually passed to `foo`. It can also mitigate confusion when overload resolution is involved and it should be visible at the call site which overload is picked. Also consider that `foo(explicit_t{})` will break when `foo`s signature is changed, while `foo({})` might silently do the wrong thing. There can be many reasons to make things explicit in code rather than implicit.

Comment: While I do like this property about marking the default constructor `explicit`, it does also require to be somewhat overly expressive, as in having to write: `auto foo() -> explicit_t { return explicit_t{}; }` opposed to simply `auto foo() -> explicit_t { return {}; }`.

Comment: @303 return type deduction detracts a bit from the point you are trying to make, its the same with `explicit_t moo(){ return {};}`. Though, I do agree. Not sure why this isnt allowed. I suppose its the same reason why `explicit_t w = {};` is not ok even though there is no danger of implicit conversions to slip in.

Comment: It's also worth noting that an explicit default constructor deviates from the behavior as the `int`s do (e.g.: invoking `void foo(int)` with `foo({})`).